# Is there a version of anaconda compiled with intel svml (Short Vector Math Library)?

Tags: python, anaconda, icc

I worked a lot on C++ projects based on intel icc/icpc compiler, which, by default, use an impressive vectorisation library, svml.

I also recently saw that anaconda now use optimizations from intel MKL (Math Kernel Library).

So my question is:

*Is there an existing version of anaconda compiled with intel svml (Short Vector Math Library), which could improve performance drastically?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intel SVML can be used implicitly by Intel Compiler's vectorizer. I'm not aware of anything in Python using SVML directly right now but [Intel is working](https://software.intel.com/python-distribution) on binding all the possible [Intel Performance Libraries](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522400) to performance-critical Python modules like Numpy/Scipy and compiles them using Intel Compiler with enabled vectorization.

These modules are now available on [Intel channel](https://anaconda.org/intel) at anaconda.org (currently in Beta version).

There is also [Intel VML](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521751) library which generalizes SVML to work with longer vectors/arrays, and it is already [used to accelerate Numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide#enabling-intels-vml-support).

#iamintel

Answer (score 1):

Using the right packages with the right arguments, you may benefit from it. If you use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org) and have [icc-rt](https://pypi.org/project/icc-rt/) installed  can (now) use Intel SVML, as detailed [on this benchmark](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html#intel-svml) (reproduced below for completeness).

The benchmark itself is a sum of square roots on a large array.

```
+-----------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
| ``@njit`` kwargs                  |  SVML  | Execution time    |
+===================================+========+===================+
| ``None``                          | No     | 5.95s             |
+-----------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
| ``None``                          | Yes    | 2.26s             |
+-----------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
| ``fastmath=True``                 | No     | 5.97s             |
+-----------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
| ``fastmath=True``                 | Yes    | 1.8s              |
+-----------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
| ``parallel=True``                 | No     | 1.36s             |
+-----------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
| ``parallel=True``                 | Yes    | 0.624s            |
+-----------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
| ``parallel=True, fastmath=True``  | No     | 1.32s             |
+-----------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
| ``parallel=True, fastmath=True``  | Yes    | 0.576s            |
+-----------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
```